# In microservice architecture, the Authentication and validation of JWT tokens should be in charge of 1 service or?

Tags: spring-boot, security, jwt, microservices, gateway

I am thinking of a design of a microservices architecture, for the security I was thinking of a AuthenticationMicroservice it will take care of generating new jwt tokens and then there is also a spring cloud gateway, my doubt is, if we want to keep single responsability principle, the gateway should receive a request and send it to the AuthenticationMicroservice so it can check if jwt token is valid??

Or is it okay to have a JwtUtils class in our gateway, that has token validation capabilities, so that we dont go to the AuthenticationService for every request just to check if token is valid

I think we could do the JwtUtils approach and still not violate the single responsability principle

Answer (score 0):

Typically if you are using a JWT token as opposed to an opaque token. The JWT token should be evaluated in the resource server. It's important that whatever system that relies on a JWT token validates it properly, eg the signature and relevant claims like the `aud` claim etc.

That said unless you are reinventing the wheel it shouldn't be an authentication microservice but an OpenID Connect Server that should be generating ID Tokens. For authorization it could be the same OpenID Connect Server returning access tokens conveying authorization information or the token from the OpenID Connect Server could be exchanged at an OAuth2 Authorization Server (Security Token Service) for an access token that conveys the authorization information to be sent to the downstream resource servers. If the resource servers require the resource owner identity this is typically conveyed in the `sub` claim of the access token.

A good read on the subject is [NIST Special Publication 800-204 Security Strategies for
Microservices-based Application Systems](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-204.pdf).